# Filling in an old basement ejector pit

Tags: concrete, basement, hole, sump

Our basement had an old bathroom in one corner that has been removed and there's an old, empty ejector pit that handled the bathroom waste.  There is also a nearby sump pit that is functional and will remain in use, so there's no future needs for this ejector pit.

I'd like to fill it in and put some concrete at the top to match the elevation & rest of the floor so I can later do an epoxy flooring finish over the whole area.

My questions:

- what's the best way to decommission and fill the ejector pit?
- Will it trap water if it's got tears or cracks in the liner?
- Should I drill some holes in the bottom for drainage before infilling?
- Should I do some sort of moisture barrier?
- Can I use a bunch of old bricks and pea gravel to fill the majority and just do concrete for the last several inches?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure that you or a future home-owner won't ever need the ejector pit again? You indicate that the bathroom has been removed, but not that a new one has been built in its place. Often, people like having a bathroom in the basement for convenience, especially if it's a finished basement.

Comment: The follow on thought from that comment: Maybe consider a flush-mount lid for the pit that can be covered with whatever kind of flooring material you're putting down. Take a picture and include measurements for where to find the pit in case anyone ever needs it in the future. It's much easier to remove a lid than it is to drill a new hole in the concrete floor. Future owners, maybe even future you, will thank you!

Comment: A new bathroom (that actually meets code) has been built elsewhere in the basement.  This older pit fed into a septic tank that no longer exists.  The expense of making this pit ever operable again is unlikely.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: Fair enough! Just wanted to point that out - some people make decisions without thinking through the consequences. It seems you have already.